# Bower CDN Fallback Solution?

Tags: javascript, package, cdn, bower, package-managers

I really like bower. Front-end package management was terrible before it. The only issue is that a lot of popular CDNs will offer *debatably* (let's not make this a debate) better performance Is there a known setup for bower packages with a CDN fallback? Or do I have to write some JavaScript for each individual package (seen it done for jQuery and similar packages)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great website that can do that for you, please check out

http://bowercdn.net/

If that isn't what you are looking for please let me know.

Comment: Was more looking for package automation that checks popular CDNs, because the only solid reason to use a CDN IMO is caching.